# tortoiseHg workbench : Select and copy multiple commit descriptions between 2 revisions

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, workbench

Is there a way to select and copy all commit messages between 2 revisions in tortoiseHg workbench.

I want basically to have the change log descriptions between 2 revisions.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the bottom of the Workbench window there's a console panel, if you can't see it go to **View> Show Console**.

Into that console window type:

```
hg log -r 1510:1513 --template '{desc}\n\n'
```

This will retrieve the values for the revisions between `-r 1510:1513` and only show you the bits specified in the template, in this case the description or commit message `{desc}`, and it puts two line breaks `\n` in at the end so each message is clearly separated from the next.

If you wanted to see the revision number along side the commit message you could use something like:

```
hg log -r 1510:1513 --template '{rev}: {desc}\n\n'
```

`{rev}` gives you the friendly revision number.

[hg log](https://www.selenic.com/hg/help/log) with [revsets](https://www.selenic.com/hg/help/revsets) (the bit that defines what revisions you want to look at, in this case `-r 1510:1513`) and [templates](https://www.selenic.com/hg/help/templates) is extremely powerful and can be manipulated to get almost any information you want out of Mercurial changesets.

Comment: Excellent ! Thanks. No UI way to do it ?

Comment: No, I don't think there's any UI way to do it.